# Understanding the logic of Tkinter mainloop() and why variables are not reassigned their original values?

Tags: python, tkinter

From my understanding `window.mainloop()` keeps repeating the GUI code so that the window and its widgets stay on the screen. Why, therefore, can a variable (such as `canvastext`) be updated and stay updated? Surely the logic of `window.mainloop()` would overwrite `canvastext` so that it once again has the text value 'Hi' instead of the new spinbox value?
It may be that I have completely misunderstood what `window.mainloop()` does but if it does make the program keep looping through the code then why aren't variables reassigned their original values?

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100

def hello():
    #print spin value
    print ("Spin Value:")
    number = v.get()
    print(number)
    #update text with variable value
    txt = v.get()
    global canvastext
    canvas1.delete(canvastext)
    canvas1.update()
    canvastext = canvas1.create_text(50, 50, text = txt)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

#canvas and drawing
canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 200, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
rect = canvas1.create_rectangle(*coord, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")
canvastext = canvas1.create_text(50, 50, text ="Hi")

# create a toplevel menu
menubar = Menu(window)

firstmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
firstmenu.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
firstmenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=window.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu1", menu=firstmenu)

secondmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
secondmenu.add_command(label="Hi!", command=hello)
secondmenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=window.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu2", menu=secondmenu)

window.config(menu=menubar)

#spinboxes and capturing value
v=IntVar()
spin = Spinbox(window, textvariable=v, from_=1, to = 10)
spin.grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky= W)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "From my understanding window.mainloop() keeps repeating the GUI code
>   so that the window and its widgets stay on the screen"

Not exactly. It doesn't "keep repeating" anything, except to keep looking for events and dispatching the handlers for the events. It doesn't re-run any of your code. mainloop is very simple, it's not much different than this:

```
while (the_main_window_hasnt_been_destroyed):
    event=event_queue.pop()
    event.handle()
```

I don't understand your question about variables getting reset. The event loop by itself does not alter anything. All it does is wait for events and then call the appropriate handler. If a handler changes a variable, it gets changed. If not, it stays the same.

Comment: Thanks again Bryan. That now makes perfect sense. My misunderstandings was to think that the main code gets re-execute on each loop so I thought that if the function updated the canvastext variable, it would be overwritten again when the following mainloop iteration occurs. But now knowing that the main code isn't executed over and over again and instead it just waits for events, it makes sense why variables stay changed. Thanks again!