# How can I fix the repetitive root.mainloop() calls in the change() function? I want to change an image with a change in the scroll bars

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

There are 10 sliders, and each slider value-change changes the image in the window. But I can't find a way to do this without calling root.mainloop() in the change() function. This although causes stack overflow eventually and i checked that by printing traceback length('memory' variable).

```
root = tk.Tk()

class SliderClass:
    def __init__(self,i,j):
        global no
        self.no = no
        self.w = Scale(root, label="PCA_feature "+str(self.no+1), 
            from_=10, to=-10, tickinterval=0.1, orient=HORIZONTAL, showvalue=0)
        self.w.grid(row=i,column=j)
        self.w.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.change)
        self.w.set(np.clip(z[self.no],-10.0,10.0))
        no +=1

    def change(self, event):
        memory = ''.join(traceback.format_stack())
        print(len(memory))
        z[self.no] = self.w.get()
        z_inv = pca.inverse_transform(z).reshape((1,-1))
        im = G.layers[2].predict(z_inv)
        im = (0.5 * im + 0.5)*255
        im = im[0,:,:,:].astype('uint8')
        im = cv2.resize(im,(150,150))
        im = Image.fromarray(im)
        im = PhotoImage(im)
        panel.configure(image=im)
        root.mainloop()

im = Image.fromarray(im)
im = PhotoImage(im)
panel = Label(root, image = im, width=300,height=300)
panel.grid(rowspan=2,column=0)

r,c = 2,5
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(1,c+1):
        s = SliderClass(i,j)
        sliders.append(s)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What happens if you just don't call mainloop() inside change? Typically you don't need to "manually hand off" control back to the mainloop. Merely returning will do that automatically.

Comment: The image that I am supposed to change disappears.

Comment: Read [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424553/7414759) and [Understanding the logic of Tkinter mainloop()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089368/7414759)

Comment: Thank you so much :D The first link solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to call `mainloop` in your function. It should be called exactly once for the life of your program.

The fact that the image doesn't show when you remove the call to `mainloop` is because you aren't storing a reference to the image so it gets deleted by the garbage collector when the function goes out of scope. By running `mainloop` in the function you prevent that from happening, but cause even worse problems (namely, the one you're writing about)

In addition to removing the call to `mainloop` inside your function, you need to save a reference to the image object. A simple change would be to use an attribute like `self.im` rather than the local variable `im`.